# Magento 2.3: How do i solve this, Not registered handle, on custom form?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, adminform, di, ui-form

I'm new to `Magento`, my version is `2.3`, i'm getting this error when i open form view: `Not registered handle event_form_data_source`, i made my custom module `Plumtree_Events`, here are my files code.

**`/app/code/Plumtree/Events/etc/di.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="event_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Plumtree\Events\Model\ResourceModel\Event\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <virtualType name="Plumtree\Events\Model\ResourceModel\Event\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">plumtree_events</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Plumtree\Events\Model\ResourceModel\Event</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

**`/app/code/Plumtree/Events/view/adminhtml/layout/event_event_newaction.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="event_event_edit"/>
    <body/>
</page>
```

**`/app/code/Plumtree/Events/view/adminhtml/layout/event_event_edit.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="event_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**`/app/code/Plumtree/Events/view/adminhtml/ui_component/event_form.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">event_form.event_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">event_form.event_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Event Form</item>
        <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <dataSource name="event_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">event_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">events_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="event">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Event Fieldset</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <!-- This field represents form id and is hidden -->
        <field name="events_id" formElement="input">
         ...........
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should update your code:

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">event_form.event_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">event_form.event_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Event Form</item>
    <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
    </item>
</argument>

<dataSource name="event_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">event_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">events_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

Please check.

Comment: Thank for mark as right answer. :)

Comment: can you please explain it.

Comment: Please add text that explains what is changed and how it was wrong. This is a relatively useless answer as it is